# Upload directory for two different hosts

Tags: php, mysql, server-side

I have two different services, websites on two different hosts, and there's one shared thing - Upload directory. Do you have some idea, how to solve that problem ? Or just how to share one admin Panel between two different websites, on two different hosts ?

Comment: So just for clarification, there's one upload script that needs to upload to two separate servers?

Comment: Not exacly.. there is two websites, two upload scripts on two hosts and i need to put uploaded files into one, shared folder. Which will be avaliable for those two servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you set up an FTP server, then upload the files to that FTP.

I normally use [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) library when working with FTPs (this library supports SFTP)

You will have access to all the files on the FTP from any of the servers.

**Sample usage:**

```
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
$sftp->login('username', 'password');
$sftp->chdir('upload');
$sftp->put('filename.remote', 'xxx'); // string to be uploaded or file_get_contents('local.file')
$sftp->put('filename.remote', 'local.file', NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
$remoteFileContent = $sftp->get('filename.remote');
$sftp->get('filename.remote', 'local.file'); // copy remote file
$sftp->delete('filename.remote'); // delete file
```

**PS:** Removed error handling and includes for ease of reading

Comment: It's very got solution, but sorry, i forgot about one important thing. Server use SFTP protocol to transfer data. Whether the library supports SFTP?

Comment: Yes, it supports SFTP, I used exactly this recently.

Comment: I can't test it now because im doing other things but ill check it tomorrow and give you feedback.
BTW, it looks good :) Thanks for now :)

Answer (score 0):

If they are on the same server, have both websites write to the same directory (will need to give them both permission to do so).

Comment: They are on the same server, but on different accounts. Fo log in to both i must use different credentials.